# SSRS open link in another browser tab

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to open a report into another tab in the same browser. I have tried the following with no success

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://xxx-xxxxxxxxx/Reports/report/Ventes/subrptRevenuParSuccusale&rs:Command=Render')"
```

it always give me the path of the element is not valid .....
Then I tried

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://xxx-xxxxxxxxx/Reports/report/Ventes/subrptRevenuParSuccusale')"
```

Works fine, the I tried to pass a paramneter, but no success

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://xxx-xxxxxxxxx/Reports/report/Ventes/subrptRevenuParSuccusale&rs:Command=Render&TransNo="+Fields!TRANSACTIONNO.Value+"')"
```

The minute I add the section &rs:Command=Render....., nothing works
Can someone explain to me what I am missing here and why it is not working as it should

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the SSRS reportserver not, the SSRS portal address

Something like this

```
http://myServerName/reportserver/?%2FMY%20FOLDER%2FMY%20REPORT%20NAME&myParameterName=1234
```

This will open The report in the `MY FOLDER` folder called `MY REPORT NAME` and pass in `1234` to the parameter called `myParameterName`

I find it easier to build these as expressions in the URL expression. Here's an exmaple

```
=Globals.ReportServerUrl
+ "?/myFolder/my+Report+Name" 
+ "&CountryID=" + cStr(Fields!CountryID.Value)
+ "&CategoryID=" + cStr(Fields!CategoryID.Value)
+ "&RecordedPeriodID=" + cStr(Parameters!PeriodID.Value)
+ "&rc:Parameters=Collapsed"
```

Here we want to to open the "my report name" report from "my folder" and pass in 3 parameters, finally I set a property to hide the parameters panel.

Note: I used the built-in SSRS `Globals!ReportServerUrl` variable to get the server name so it works on development and production servers with no modification required.

Wrap this in you javascript window.open and it should work.

Comment: I am referencing the report server not the portal address, this is the actual address http://xxx-vsrvsql01/Reports/...... (except for the 3 x)

Comment: If you add a text box showing what Globals!ReportServerUrl returns does it match? I ask because the default for the reportserver service address is `ReportServer` whereas the portal address is `Reports`

Comment: does not match, found out that Edge is displaying  
http://sso-vsrvsql01/ReportServer and Chrome  
http://ia.regulvar.com/ReportServer and the funny part is that we have only 1 report server

Comment: Check the SSRS config and make sure you use the service address. I have done this on several occasions and it always works using the methods I outlined.